# Which file to modify when using mongodb ruby driver to connect rails API application with mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I am following this tutorial to make a rails RESTful API application:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-one

But I want to use `mongodb` database instead of `sqlite`. So I created the application by running this command:

`rails new Research_and_Publications --api -T --skip-active-record`

Then, to connect with mongodb, I am following this link:

https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/quick-start/

But I cannot get where to put this piece of code:

```
require 'mongo'
client = Mongo::Client.new([ '127.0.0.1:27017' ], :database => 'test')
client = Mongo::Client.new([ '127.0.0.1:27017' ], :database => 'test')
db = client.database

db.collections # returns a list of collection objects
db.collection_names # returns a list of collection names`
```

Please help me in which file should I add this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mongoid](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid) is the official Object Document Mapper framework for MongoDB in Ruby. I would suggest you to use that in your application.

Add `mongoid` gem in your `Gemfile` as below:

```
gem 'mongoid', '~> 6.1.0'
```

and run `bundle install`

Next, generate the config file `your_app/config/mongoid.yml` by running the following command:

```
rails g mongoid:config
```

And you are all set. Follow the [tutorials](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/mongoid-tutorials-6.1/) on mongoDB site to help you further set up models, configuration, etc.